# CoreBluetooth: connect ipad with mac mini

Tags: ios, ipad, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on an application which makes two devices communicate via Bluetooth LE. 
The application runs on iPad and has the CBCentralManager object and it should connect to my macmini via bluetooth but centralManager didDiscoverPeripheral is never called. I'm checking if the bluetooth device is powered on and then I call scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil.

As I know, both devices have bluetooth 4.0 LE and it should work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is one of them set as a Peripheral and the other set as an Central? Can you find the other with `LightBlue`?

Comment: Where can i set them as peripheral or central? I installed LightBlue on both OSs but it seems i can simulate a peripheral only on iPad. OS X version of lightblue has only peripheral discovery.

Comment: Check the Apple Sample Code BTLE Transfer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for help ! I didn't figure out how to make my macmini be a peripheral using iOS as long as the simulator doesn't support bluetooth capability anymore but lucky I found an application on github which does the job for OS X: https://github.com/sandeepmistry/osx-ble-peripheral